# How to verify if test is correctly implemented via code?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

#### Introduction

I am trying to verify if the created tests pass my criteria/scenario.

#### Problem

Suppose we have two classes: SomeService.java and SomeRepository.java. Methods inside SomeService are already implemented. At the other hand, methods in SomeRepository are not yet implemented.

Now, using Mockito framework I want to mock SomeRepository. For instance:

```java
@Mock SomeRepository repository;

@Test
public String someMethod() {
  SomeService service = new SomeService(repository);
  when(repository..).doReturn(...);
  String result = service.call();
  assertTrue(result).isNotNull();
}
```

#### Question

Is it possible to code some piece of logic (test case) in such a way that it will check for me, for instance:

for someMethod test, I want to have:
 1. repository.callSth() should return some string
 2. result should be checked for nullability

#### Note

I have to use Mockito.

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: You can write a test suite for your test suite, but generally one just concludes from one's tests passing that the tests and code under test validate each other.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I do not get it, always thought Test Suite is just for test aggregation?

Comment: @NicolasCage John is using "test suite" as an encompassing phrase to refer to all your test code, not as a reference to any specific JUnit `TestSuite` class.

Comment: sorry but none of above answer my question.